# how to Concatenate Button Content in xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, concatenation

I tried to concatenate two string as `Button` content in XAML. But It is not working. I tried like below:

```
<Button Content=""String1"+{DynamicResource String2}"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use Multibinding concept.  [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20160116171455/http://www.blogs.intuidev.com/post/2010/04/12/ConcatenateFieldsMultiValueConverter.aspx) It will help you well.

Answer (score 11):

The code in XAML is the following:

```
 <Button>
        <TextBlock>
            <Run Text="String1"/>
            <Run Text="{DynamicResource String2}"/>
        </TextBlock>
 </Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MultiBinding` with `StringFormat` parameter:

```
<Button>
    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}{1}">
        <Binding>
            <Binding.Source>
                <sys:String> String1 </sys:String>
            </Binding.Source>
        </Binding>
        <Binding Path="{DynamicResource String2}" />
    </MultiBinding>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple, not terribly scalable way to deal with this would be:

```
<Window x:Class="AdHocWPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <System:String x:Key="String2">String2</System:String>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button>
        <TextBlock>
            <System:String>String1 </System:String>
            <TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource String2}"/>
        </TextBlock>
    </Button>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

TextBlocks are basically little flowdocuments, so they're very flexible.

Answer (score 0):

How about binding the content to a value in the view model or model and then you can set this a lot more easily to what you want dynamically and have a lot more control over it. Of course you'd have to be using MVVM..

however, 2kay's answer is better...